# How to parse multiple rows with concatenated data into a single column

Tags: sql, excel, rows, delimited

I have an excel spreadsheet with delimited information (tracking #s) in various rows:

```
row a 630521*630621*630215*610517
row b 630522*630611
row c 630531*630651*630265
row d 630524
```

I would like to organize all rows of tracking #s, separated by a "*", into one column.  Can you tell me how this is possible?  I have 4,000+ rows like this with up to 21 tracking #s (variable) in each row that I want to convert to one column with multiple rows.

```
col a
630521
630621
630215
610517
630522
630611
630531
630651
630265
630524
```

Comment: you just want to replace the * with a space and keep what's on the rows the same?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this with or without VBA?

Comment: i would've done this with vba but we were able to pull it off without vba @TheEngineer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in Excel:

1. Highlight your column
2. On the Data menu, select Text to Columns => Delimited => Next => Other * => Finish
3. Then Copy/Paste each of the resultant columns into a single column and sort it to put the blanks at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you.  I used # 1 & 2 and then the response from pnuts for #3.

Answer (score 0):

To save step 3. in Ron Smith's answer where you have a LOT of rows, you might add a blank row at the top and on the left, select you entire range (including all the blanks), apply the technique detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651), delete the columns labelled `Row` and `Column` then filter to delete blank rows from column labelled `Value`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was much needed for step 3 from Ron.  I appreciate the assistance.